# Deploying Python on Nginx Server Google Cloud

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, gcloud, google-api-nodejs-client, gcloud-node

I am building an application in **Node.js**. That application runs a child process which includes a python script. I deploy my application in **gcloud** which shows **502-Bad Gateway (ngix)**. Help will be more appreciated.

Here is my code..

```
app.post('/webhook/', function (req, res) {
 responseMessage("hi").then(function(msg){
    console.log("msg ==>", msg);
    res.send({response:msg});
    // res.sendStatus(200)
 });
})

function responseMessage(message){
  var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
  var py    = spawn('python3.6', ['suman.py']),
  data = "suman",
  dataString = 's';
  data=message;
  py.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        if(data){
                py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
                        dataString = data;
                        console.log('data', data);
                        resolve(data);
                });
                py.stdout.on('end', function(){
                  console.log('lets c',dataString);
                         resolve(dataString);
                });
                py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                py.stdin.end();
                // res.end();
              } else {
                     reject({message: 'input shouldnt be null' })
             }
       });

     }
```

Server Error

    
        502 Bad Gateway

## 502 Bad Gateway

nginx

Comment: What specific command are you using to deploy your application?  Are you running on App Engine?  Compute Engine?

Comment: Also - do you know if your site is running at all?  Can you hit a default page or something, and validate it works?  Also, noticed you're not handling the promise reject up in your route handler.

Comment: Well it was because of not enabling the port thank you for your answers @JustinBeckwith